Envíar msj de whatsapp a través de mi aplicacion NextJS
Estoy desarrollando un aplicación para gestionar turnos y me gustaría que una vez que la persona reserve el turno se le envíe un msj automáticamente a su whatsaap.
Que librería me recomiendan usar, ya que no encuentre que me sirva.
Muchas gracias.
